# Convert a single node to distributed java application with Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, vert.x, hazelcast-jet

We have a current java application built with Vert.x using simple local `HashMaps`. In order to distribute our application on several nodes, we would like to replace local HashMaps by a single Hazelcast `IMap`.

Basically we have our 2 `HashMaps` :

```
Map<String, Group> // <groupId - group>
Map<String, Set<String>  // <memberId - set of groupIds>
```

We have 2 `HashMaps` in order to query easily our groups by their ids and to know to which groups belong our members.

However, with `IMap`, according to documentation, it should be possible to create only one map :

```
IMap<String, Group> // <groupId - group>

class Group {
  String id;
  Set<Member> members;
}

class Member {
  String id;
  // some data
}
```

and we should be able to perform :

```
Collection<Group> groups = imap.values(Predicates.in("members", varargs of member ids))
```

So, I have 4 questions :

1. Could you confirm this behavior is possible with IMap ?
2. If yes, is it possible the collection of groups returned by `imap.values` contain duplicates (same groupId) ? Do I have to perform a kind of `distinct` operation ?
3. We are not sure if we should use Vertx + Hazelcast, or move all the processing code to Hazelcast Jet. What would be the advantages to move to Hazelcast Jet only ?
4. If we use Hazelcast Jet, is it possible to use IMap.values(Predicate) feature inside `StreamStage` like that :

```
StreamStage.flatMap(memberIds -> Traversers.traverseIterable(imap.values(Predicates.in("memberIds", memberIds.toArray(new String[0])))
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes
2. it should not contain duplicates if your original map doesn't contain them and the IMap isn't concurrently updated
3. depends on your use case, I can't tell in general
4. This is not good as the `imap.values` call is blocking and the function in `flatMap` must not block. By blocking I mean it does blocking IO operations. Also you can't capture the `imap` instance from a local variable because it's not serializable and Jet can't send it to the member. But you can use `mapUsingService` and use `ServiceFactories.imapService` like this:

```java
 .mapUsingService(
         ServiceFactories.iMapService("my_map").toNonCooperative(),
         (imap, memberIds) -> 
             imap.values(Predicates.in("memberIds", memberIds.toArray(new String[0]))))
```